# What is the Username for SEGANET?

Tags: sonic-dreams-collection

I'm trying to login to SEGANET (I hear it's how you can play Eggman Origins).

I think I got the right password from the tv, but I haven't found a username that works. I've tried looking through the attic and _rattle_data, but to no avail.

What is the username needed for SEGANET?

Extra question: Is the username/password specific to a certain server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The username: mjstudio

The password: wh1t3Glove

these will allow you to play eggman origins( Play Make My Sonic first and upload a screenshot).

Answer (score -4):

Here you go:

This video provides both the username and password. You were right, the password is from the TV in Sonic's apartment, and you find the username in the crib in one of the cute little frames on the wall.

Comment: In case the video goes down, it'd benefit to put the relevant information in the answer itself